# Codeigniter 4 Pagination not properly filter when use searching

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to convert my code from codeigniter3 to codeigniter4 . All function work properly in ci3 but some function not work after im convert to ci4.

When i make searching on search box, pagination show properly if data not more than 10 (default per/page 10).. But when result more than 10, result was appear in one page and pagination also appear with no proper page. Supposedly page will only show according to total of result.

Controller (Homes.php)

```
public function posts()
{
    $homemodel = new \App\Models\Homemodel(); // Assuming Homemodel is in the Models folder

    $columns = ['id', 'title', 'body', 'created_at', 'id'];

    $limit = $this->request->getPost('length');
    $start = $this->request->getPost('start');
    $order = $columns[$this->request->getPost('order')[0]['column']];
    $dir = $this->request->getPost('order')[0]['dir'];

    $totalData = $homemodel->allPostsCount();  // Adjusted method name

    $totalFiltered = $totalData;

    if (empty($this->request->getPost('search')['value'])) {
        $posts = $homemodel->allPosts($limit, $start, $order, $dir);  // Adjusted method name
    } else {
        $search = $this->request->getPost('search')['value'];

        $posts =  $homemodel->postsSearch($limit, $start, $search, $order, $dir);  // Adjusted method name

        $totalFiltered = $homemodel->postsSearchCount($search);  // Adjusted method name
    }

    $data = [];
    if (!empty($posts)) {
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $nestedData['id'] = $post['id'];
            $nestedData['title'] = $post['title'];
            $nestedData['body'] = substr(strip_tags($post['body']), 0, 50) . "...";
            $nestedData['created_at'] = date('j M Y h:i a', strtotime($post['created_at']));

            $data[] = $nestedData;
        }
    }

    $json_data = [
        "draw"            => intval($this->request->getPost('draw')),
        "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
        "data"            => $data,
    ];

    return $this->response->setJSON($json_data);
}
```

My Model (Homemodel.php)

```
class Homemodel extends Model {
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function allPostsCount()
    {
        return $this->countAll();
    }

    public function allPosts($limit, $start, $col, $dir)
    {
        return $this->select('*')
            ->limit($limit, $start)
            ->orderBy($col, $dir)
            ->paginate($limit);
    }

    public function postsSearch($limit, $start, $search, $col, $dir)
    {
        return $this->select('*')
            ->like('id', $search)
            ->orLike('title', $search)
            ->limit($limit, $start)
            ->orderBy($col, $dir)
            ->findAll();
    }

    public function postsSearchCount($search)
    {
        return $this->like('id', $search)
            ->orLike('title', $search)
            ->countAllResults();
    }
 }
```

My View (homes.php)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="posts">
            <thead>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Body</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
            </thead>                
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#posts').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('homes/posts') ?>", // Use site_url() for proper URL generation
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {
                    '<?php echo csrf_token() ?>': '<?php echo csrf_hash() ?>'
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "title" },
                { "data": "body" },
                { "data": "created_at" },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Result when I'm trying search data with only have 1 result, show proper pagination

[image]

Result when I'm trying search data with have more than 10 result, result was dump into one page with not proper pagination

[image]

continue ...

[image]

my goal is when make searching and result is more than 10 (depend on limit set), result will show with proper page.

I'm seeking any help. Thank You